# How to get an array from IEnumerable data?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Suppose there is IEnumerable data as

```
IEnumerable values=[
                   {"EM_NAME":"Abu Dhabi"},
                   {"EM_NAME":"Ajman"},
                   {"EM_NAME":"Dubai"},
                   {"EM_NAME":"Fujairah"}, 
                   {"EM_NAME":"Ras al Khaimah"},
                   {"EM_NAME":"Sharjah"},
                   {"EM_NAME":"Umm al Quwain"}
                   ]
```

Is there any way to get an array like this without using loop

```
array=[
       "Abu Dhabi",
       "Ajman",
       "Dubai",
       "Fujairah",
       "Ras al Khaimah",
       "Sharjah",         
       "Umm al Quwain"
       ]
```

**Edit:** Tried ToArray() as well

Comment: use the `ToArray` method.

Comment: what's wrong with loop? You can use linq query but basically it creates the same loop

Comment: @GuruStron:linq query is better or loop?

Comment: @abc123 what do you mean by "better"?

Comment: which 1 is better in performance looping or using linq query

Comment: @abc123 it pretty much the same, linq queries are little more slower cause they internally use the same loops so you get a little overhead. The best practice depends on what you need: Development speed and maintainability - LINQ; 
Performance (according to profiling tools) - manual code

Answer (score 2):

`MyEntityType[] array = values.Cast<MyEntityType>().ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

just use `IEnumerable.ToArray()`

```
values.ToArray() in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the static `Enumerable.ToArray` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx